# Sign of an infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, infinite-product

Let $c\in (0,1)$ and $a=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.
How can I prove that the following product is strictly positive?

$$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-ca^i}{1+ca^i}>0$$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$a=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies 0<a<1$$

So, for $ i>0$,

$$0<a^i<1$$
and
$$0<ca^i<c<1$$

Comment: Yes, This will give me a lower bound $\prod_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1-ca^i}{2}$. But this is equal to $0$. I need a strictly positive lower bound.

Comment: @user268193 Proving that $P>0$ (is strictly positive) and that $P>a>0$ are different things. If your task was just to show that $P>0$, as you wrote in the question you don't need a nonzero lower bound.

Comment: In fact, there is no nonzero lower bound, since when $c=(1-\varepsilon)$, the product can be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to see if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \ln(\frac{1-ca^i}{1+ca^i})$ converges.

Since $\ln(\frac{1-ca^i}{1+ca^i}) \sim -2ca^i$ the corresponding series are of the same nature, and since the later converges, so does the first one. 
Hence $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \ln(\frac{1-ca^i}{1+ca^i}) \neq -\infty$, so your product ($\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-ca^i}{1+ca^i} =e^{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \ln(\frac{1-ca^i}{1+ca^i})}$) is strictly positive.

Answer (score 0):

A nice result here:

Thm: If $0<b_n<1,$ then $\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-b_n)>0$ iff $\sum b_n<\infty.$

The theorem follows by applying the logarithm to the product and using the inequality $-x/2>\ln(1-x)>-x,$ which holds for small $x>0.$ Assuming the theorem, note the factors in your product equal $1-b_n,$ where

$$b_n =\frac{2ca^n}{1+ca^n}.$$

The theorem then gives you the desired result.